# MapActivity Force Closes, Touch Event fires recklessly

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, touch-event

I have a MapActivity which has a touch event.

In the touch event:

- I get the current geocodes
- Put an overlay image on that location.
- and set it as the center of the mapview.

This seems to work fine and as expected for a while. But then the application force closes. I think the touch event is being fired like crazy even when nothing's being touched. I know that because I had put a toast set up that shows the longitude and lattitude of the touched position. and it keeps showing up even when nothing's touched.

I cant seem to accurately position the problem, let alone fixing it. Here's the touch event for my mapActivity

```
private void LocationStuffs(double latitude, double longitude){
    itemizedOverlay.clear();
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem((int)latitude, (int)longitude, "place"); 
    mapView.invalidate();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)latitude, (int)longitude)); 
    mc.setZoom(20);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView){
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(),
                    (int) event.getY());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +
                            p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            latitude = p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            longitude = p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
            LocationStuffs(latitude*1E6, longitude*1E6);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If your app crashes you should always post your LogCat errors.

Comment: Yes it will be called many times. To solve this, save the location of the event when `if(event.getAction() == 1)` then in subsequent calls, check if the new location is in the proximity of the saved location; If it is the case, do not enter the if block again. And as @Sam said, post your logcat.

Comment: Thank You. that might solve the problem. But I dont understand why the touchevent is being fired so often? Isnt it supposed to fire only when the map is touched? Or does it work in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return statement to return true:

```
return true;
```

Basically, what that does is that it tells the system that you have handled the touchevent. Let me know if that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have few errors in your code:

1- You need a  "return true" statement before you close the "if" statement  in the "onTouchEvent" method. This tells the system that the event has been handled and it should be consumed. That's probably the reason for multiple touchs.

2- the "mapView.invalidate();" should be moved to the end of your "LocationStuffs" method, as you want to have you screen redrawn after you have add the new location and not before.

3- You are adding repeatedly the same itemizedOverlay to the mapview. After calling your "LocationStuffs" method 10 times, you will have the same overlay added 10 times to the overlays list. You should add the Itemizedoverlay only once, outside this method (on the onCreate or onResume for example)

good luck